# Error on first Kivy/Buildozer android project

Tags: kivy, buildozer

Trying to run Kivy with buildozer on Ubuntu 16.04, 
(startup-demo-project pong) I get an error
on command

```
buildozer android debug deploy
```

After:
     ....
     [DEBUG]:       BUILD SUCCESSFUL
     ....

at the end of the build there is an error message:

```
....
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/home/std/Dokumente/python  
/Kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/build/outputs  
/apk/myapp-debug.apk'
```

My installation is according to:
  http://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
for Ubuntu 16.04.

Also 
    buildozer serve
does not show anything useful, only:

```
Directory listing for /
```

as response to call:

```
http://localhost:8000
```

Buildozer console says:

```
192.168.178.22 - - [15/Apr/2018 21:43:12] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.178.22 - - [15/Apr/2018 21:43:12] code 404, message File not found
```

Annotation:
I changed the log_level = 2 for more information, but could not figure out where to find the relevant log file or where to get more information about the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/home/std/Dokumente/python  /Kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/build/outputs  /apk/myapp-debug.apk'
```

## Solution

Use sudo to change and recompile android.py for Python 2.7. Please do the following at terminal window:

### Step 1

Change directory

```
cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/targets
```

### Step 2

Make backup copies of android.py and android.pyc

```
sudo cp android.py android-orig.py
sudo cp android.pyc android-orig.pyc
```

### Step 3

Use an editor to make changes to android.py

```
sudo gedit android.py
```

### Step 4

Insert the following import before `import sys`

```
from distutils.version import LooseVersion
```

### Step 5

Add the following codes after line 791 (`# XXX found how the apk name is really built from the title`). *Note: **__sdk_dir** (double underscore)*. Please refer to print screens below for details.

```
    __sdk_dir = self.android_sdk_dir
    build_tools_versions = os.listdir(join(__sdk_dir, 'build-tools'))
    build_tools_versions = sorted(build_tools_versions, key=LooseVersion)
    build_tools_version = build_tools_versions[-1]

    gradle_files = ["build.gradle", "gradle", "gradlew"]
    is_gradle_build = any((
        exists(join(dist_dir, x)) for x in gradle_files)) and build_tools_version >= '25.0'

    if is_gradle_build:
```

### Step 6

Save the changes.

### Step 7

Compile android.py

#### At shell prompt

```
sudo python -m py_compile a--ndroid.py
```

#### or invoke Python Interpreter Interactive Shell

```
sudo python
>>> import py_compile
>>> py_compile.compile('android.py')
```

### Step 8

At your project folder, run

```
buildozer android debug
```

## Pictures

### Changes Part 1 - from distutils.version import LooseVersion

[image: Img01 - import LooseVersion]

### Changes Part 2

[image: Img02 - remaining changes]

### Compile android.py

[image: Img03 - Compile android.py]

### After Changes @ local Buildozer - App deployed to Acer Android tablet

[image: Img04 @ local Buildozer - App deployed]

### After Changes @ Buildozer VM - Successful APK

[image]

### Before Changes @ local Buildozer - IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

[image: Img06 @ local Buildozer - IOError: Errno 2]

### Before Changes @ Buildozer VM - IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

[image: Img07 @ BuildozerVM - IOError: Errno 2]