# Error occurs during compilation for Android

Tags: android, python, kivy

I'm testing my game built with Kivy library and trying to deploy it on my Android phone. During the compilation I'm getting this error output:

```
...
...
File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('buildozer==0.34', 'console_scripts', 'buildozer')()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/buildozer/scripts/client.py",             line 13, in main
Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 1058, in run_command
self.target.run_commands(args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 92, in run_commands
func(args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 104, in cmd_debug
self.buildozer.build()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 212, in build
self.target.build_package()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 817, in build_package
copyfile(join(apk_dir, apk), join(self.buildozer.bin_dir, apk_dest))
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 114, in copyfile
with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/mark/space_shooter/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/build/outputs/apk/myapp-debug.apk'
```

I've studied numerous tutorials about deploying, however, none of them spoke about errors occuring during compilation.
Obviously, the compiler can't seem to find file in directory but I presume that file supposed to be created during the compilation.
I'm using Python 3.5 for designing the app and 2.7 for the compiler.

How can I troubleshoot this error ?

Comment: Please refer [IOError: Errno 2 No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49846023/error-on-first-kivy-buildozer-android-project)

Comment: @ikolim  Thanks for the link but I won't be doing any changes suggested in similar topics where it's very unclear whether the proposed solution actually works. I see that the questioner has identical problem as me but the developer who proposed the solution got no feedback whether it works.

Comment: I just noticed you suggested the solution.

Comment: I had the same problem and the fix solved the problem as per screen print in my post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error on first Kivy/Buildozer android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49846023/error-on-first-kivy-buildozer-android-project)