# command failed: ./distributr.sh -m "kivy" -d "main"

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

recently I have started python-for-android on my Ubuntu 16.0 Lts..currently I am
having trouble while packing my first test python module into `.apk` using `buildozer 0.32`. Before v0.32 I was working with v0.35, with that version I received the following errors:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/home/kivy/reyyy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/mainApp/build/outputs/apk/mainApp-debug.apk'
```

So I shifted the from v0.35 to v0.32 with kivy and python2.7 and now have new errors:

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:416: recipe for target 'python' failed
make: ***[python] Erroe 1
#command failed: ./distributr.sh -m "kivy" -d "main"
```

Comment: Upgrade Buildozer to v0.35. Use sudo to change and compile android.py to solve `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` as specified in [IOError: \[Errno 2\] No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49846023/error-on-first-kivy-buildozer-android-project)

Comment: How can i upgrade Buildozer i tried but its showing 0.34 now as max version

Comment: v0.34 is the stable version. You can use this.

Comment: means with v0.34  i will have only io error right :) ?

Comment: v0.35-dev also has the IOError. First try `buildozer android debug` without the fix. If it fails with that error then apply the fix and retry.

Comment: how can i install dev version may be i am not sure but i think dev version has been removed

Comment: I am using the stable version, v0.34. The *dev* or development version is unstable.