# Unable to create APK file from kivy using buildozer

Tags: kivy

[image]

I have tried using this on virtual machine on windows. Please someone help in pointing out what went wrong.The error is shown in the picture. Just an empty Bin folder is created.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error on first Kivy/Buildozer android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49846023/error-on-first-kivy-buildozer-android-project)

Comment: Also, please do not post error messages in pictures. See: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to write a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).